# Syntax error with symfony autogenerated functions in netbeans8.2

Tags: symfony, netbeans, php-7

I'm learning symfony frameworks with 4.~ version.
Using Netbeans 8.2 IDE i always got a error message on autogenerated functions of my class where return indications contains "?":

[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmfSM.png)

Using Eclipse ide i don't get this error.

When i simply delete the "?" i don't get any error message from netbeans IDE but my symfony project crash.

I'd like to know if there is a solution. thanks for reading, helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like NetBeans does not recognize [nullable types](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types), which is a relatively new feature introduced with PHP 7.1.

As long as you run the code with PHP 7.1, everything should work, but with older PHP versions this will produce fatal errors. This is exactly what NetBeans warns you about. There was a ticket in the issue tracker for adding detection for the new features and it is already closed, so I assume updating NetBeans should fix this: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=268317

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have check for new update on eclipse and don't find anything.
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)

Comment: Reading the comments it seems this feature will ship in Netbeans 9. So, you either have to wait or switch to a different IDE like Eclipse or PhpStorm. You could also try the nightly build, which might contain other bugs, though: http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/

Comment: i'm reading seems some nightly build can fixe the problem. i'll test and return teh experience in few hours. thank you for the link.

Comment: I test the latest dev build http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/ and the problem is solved. thank you